# AS3 - Global classes?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, global

I know global variables are supposed to be bad but is it possible to create global classes? I am creating an application and I want to have one class that handles sound. From any class I would like to be able to say soundhandler.playSound(); without having to pass references all over the place. It should just know it is there.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referring to `static` members.

Your class `SoundHandler` would have a static method called `playSound()`, which can be implemented like so:

```
package
{
    public class SoundHandler
    {
        public static function playSound():void
        {
            // @todo Logic
        }
    }
}
```

Your `playSound()` method is now accessible via:

```
SoundHandler.playSound();
```

Note: You mentioned global methods being bad, however this is a perfect candidate for these and something I would actually recommend (as much as I hate using static).

Additional: ActionScript 3's [`Math`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html) class contains mostly static members e.g. `Math.round()`

---

> Your question (comment): Do I need to initiate `SoundHandler` in the document class?

No, in fact you shouldn't make an instance of SoundHandler at all. The only requirement is that you must have `SoundHandler` imported in your current class to access it:

```
import yourpackage.SoundHandler;
```

Comment: So I would just instantiate the SoundHandler in the main document class? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @senortee See edit. Basically, you do not need to create an instance of a class to access its static elements.

Comment: Ahhhhh import. That's where I've been going wrong. Thanks so much, this is not explained elsewhere, you have just supplied a big bit of jigsaw that was missing.

Comment: @senortee You should consider a new AS3 editor like my personal favorite: [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/). This interface will automatically add imports at the top of your class as you work.

Comment: Interesting, looks good. I will take a closer look. Thanks again and have a good weekend!

Comment: If you want to initialize static variables without having to initialize the class, you could use a static constructor as well.

Comment: Hi there, could you provide an example?

Comment: @MartyWallace Cheers for the heads up. FlashDevelop is so much lighter and smoother than the Flash IDE. Collapsible functions. Joy! :)

Comment: Look into Singleton.registerClass if you want to only have one instance of a class

Comment: So here's another issue. If I import a class then call a function within it that adds an object to the stage it can't do it. Is this because it isn't in the display list itself? How can I have a globally accessible class that can add things to the display list? Thanks guys.

Comment: @senortee If you post a detailed question for the problem you're having and link to it here, I'll be able to help you out in proper depth.

Comment: Hi Marty. This was my question. Still having some issues so any help appreciated > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082820/as3-global-class-that-can-add-objects-to-stage